# Why doesnt 'autofocus: true' work on collection_select in Rails, while it works on text_field=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a form, where i try to autofocus on a collection_select, which doesnt work. It works for other form items such as number_field and text_field. I don't understand why?

Code that is working:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= form.label :invoice_number %></td>
  <td><%= form.number_field :invoice_number, value: 100, autofocus: true %></td>
</tr>
```

Code that is not working:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= form.label :customer_id %></td>
  <td><%= form.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, autofocus: true %></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_field` only has one `options` hash param: `number_field(object_name, method, options = {})`

`collection_select` has two: `collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

So, you would need to call it like this:

```
<%= form.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, {}, {autofocus: true} %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer resulted in a "undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass"-error. Got it working by swapping {} for nil:
<%= form.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, {}, {autofocus: true} %>

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Updated answer with empty hash for `options` param.